# How to use first-time and returning visitor in Cohort Analysis using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, analysis

I want to perform cohort analysis using this available data of mine.

```
month   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  All
customer_type                                                   
First-time  86  103 74  900 504 443 470 371 359 221 365 234 4128
Returning   247 355 231 1223    674 691 517 583 378 479 760 339 3308
All 326 450 296 2050    1152    1108    962 930 727 683 1096    565 6557
```

[image]

I'm following Greg Reda's work
http://www.gregreda.com/2015/08/23/cohort-analysis-with-python/

but I don't know how to consider the *customer type* field in my code.

```html
df.set_index('customer_email', inplace=True)

df['CohortGroup'] = df.groupby(level=0)['date'].min().apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m'))
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

def cohort_period(df):
    """
    Creates a `CohortPeriod` column, which is the Nth period based on the user's first purchase.
    
    Example
    -------
    Say you want to get the 3rd month for every user:
        df.sort(['UserId', 'OrderTime', inplace=True)
        df = df.groupby('UserId').apply(cohort_period)
        df[df.CohortPeriod == 3]
    """
    df['CohortPeriod'] = np.arange(len(df)) + 1
    return df

cohorts = cohorts.groupby(level=0).apply(cohort_period)

# reindex the DataFrame
cohorts.reset_index(inplace=True)
cohorts.set_index(['CohortGroup', 'CohortPeriod'], inplace=True)

# create a Series holding the total size of each CohortGroup
cohort_group_size = cohorts['TotalUsers'].groupby(level=0).first()
cohort_group_size.head()


cohorts['TotalUsers'].unstack(0)

user_retention = cohorts['TotalUsers'].unstack(0).divide(cohort_group_size, axis=1)
user_retention.head(10)
```

Update: These are the df columns that I'm working on

> customer_email     order_id    date    customer_type   product_type
> total_sales    month   product_title

Comment: Apologies @Cyttorak. Wasn't aware that my update was not implemented.

Comment: Try putting the data as text, it's easier to copy.